# Grails Plugin - Dynamic Method for Controller in Scaffolded doesn't work

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, metaclass

I have my own Grails plugin where I add a dynamic method using doWithDynamicMethods closure:

```
def doWithDynamicMethods = {ctx ->
    ['controller'].each {
         application."${it}Classes".each { theClass ->
         theClass.metaClass.myMethod = { ... }
    }
}
```

When I call this method from the controller it works fine:

```
...
myMethod()
...
```

but when I call this from a scaffolded template it cannot find this method:

```
...
def save() {
    <%= "myMethod()" %>
}
...
```

Is there any approach how to make it working? Or do I need to use some other pattern for dynamic method for scaffolded template?

Thanks for any hint:]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scaffolding template would not refer to the actual controller where you have referred as `scaffold true`. You would have to grab the actual controller in order to use the dynamic method.

That can be done through `grails.util.GrailsWebUtil` by following as shown below:

```
...
def save() {
    def actualController = GrailsWebUtil.getControllerFromRequest(request)
    actualController.myMethod() 
}
...
```

When a controller (artefact) is scaffolded then a replica of the actual controller is used at runtime for scaffolding. All the calls to the main controller is handled by the replica. In order to use the dynamic method, you would need a handle to the actual controller since the dynamic method is created of the actual controller artefact.

Comment: I know this workaround but anyway thanks for that. I was just curious if there is any other better approach cause if you generate controller by generate-all command that you would have all these unneeded method there.

Comment: @user607038 Well in this case it is a needed method for your implementation. :)